# wireless crash in android 4.3 and 4.4

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean, 4.4-kitkat

after updating my google nexus 4 android version to 4.3 , my wireless get crashed. in just one way. if it was on and i turn off my screen, and it goes in sleeping mode, after turnning on my screen it just crashed. always off , and in just two ways i could fixed it. restart or flight mode. sure i used flight mode. but it wasn't the big problem. the big one happened in version 4.4 . after this happend i can't fix it even by flight mode. just restart. now is there any solution for that?

Comment: it seems my problem was in my battery saver app (in this case 2x battery). i read a question in this site couple days ago. the problem of questioner was like me and he/she answer it, and said problem was from battery saver app. i think if i disable this option (wireless saver) it goes well. but just after disabling the hole app it fixed. for now i check it and i didn't have any problem.
p.s: i really forget the title of that question or link of it. if i find that, i set it here for others.

Comment: If that solves your problem then you can put it as an answer (and accept it) which will inform others the question has been solved.

Comment: ok. so i just copy and paste my answer. tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems my problem was in my battery saver app (in this case 2x battery). i read a question in this site couple days ago. the problem of questioner was like me and he/she answer it, and said problem was from battery saver app. i think if i disable this option (wireless saver) it goes well. but just after disabling the hole app it fixed. for now i check it and i didn't have any problem. 
p.s: i really forget the title of that question or link of it. if i find that, i set it here for others.